# If change input value from inspect element in PHP?

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a problem

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {$cars = $_POST['cars']; echo $cars;}

<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="cars[]"  value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cars[]"  value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cars[]"  value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cars[]"  value="4" />
<button>add</button>
</form>
```

How can I stop changing `value` if the user changes the input value from inspect element, or if the user changes the value it will alert me?

My attempted solution is

```
$allowe = ['1','2','3','4'];
if(in_array($_POST['cars'],$allowe)) {echo $_POST['cars'];}
```

but is not working (only works for one value).

Comment: $_POST['cars'] is a multi-d array you will have to loop it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can't just stop the user from tampering the form values. You can just compare it in your allowed values which you have already made. You can use `array_intersect` to the selected values and the allowed ones.

```
<?php
$allowed = ['1','2','3','4'];
if(!empty($_POST['cars'])) {
    $selected = $_POST['cars'];
    $compare = array_intersect($selected, $allowed);
    if(!empty($compare)) {
        echo 'values selected: ', implode(', ', $compare);
        // foreach($compare as $value) {
            // echo $value;
        // }
    }

}
?>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cars[]"  value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="cars[]"  value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="cars[]"  value="3" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="cars[]"  value="4" />
    <button>add</button>
</form>
```